# Write BigQuery query result directly to GCS - is it possible?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I tried the `bq` command line tool, but it there seems to be no way to write the results directly to GCS. The only way I can see is working is:

1. query -> table -> export
2. query -> console -> local CSV file -> upload to GCS

I'm looking for a way to directly write the results to GCS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write your query results directly to GCS. The easiest way, as you've already pointed out, is to:

1. Write your query results to an output table
2. Export your table to GCS

You easily do this in the web UI.

You could also write a [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) pipeline that reads from BigQuery using `BigQuery.IO.Read.fromQuery(<your_query>)`, and write the results directly to GCS.