# Exporting the Big query result as CSV generates blank file

Tags: php, csv, google-bigquery, cloud

Currently I am using Google Big query to match two tables and export the query result as CSV file in GCS.

I can't find a way to directly export the query result as CSV in GCS through API, whereas it is readily available in Google cloud console.

So I am creating a table dynamically with same column name and type as query output and inserts the record in the table. However as soon as I did it, Streaming buffer is created before actual table is populated with data. It is taking around 90 minutes to mature the table.

If I export that table (with active streaming buffer) as CSV in GCS, sometimes the exported file contains only the column header and no row data is exported.

Is there a way to overcome the situation?

I am using [google cloud php API](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiilqHA1rPVAhWLu48KHWh6BoYQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FGoogleCloudPlatform%2Fgoogle-cloud-php&usg=AFQjCNG8CywNs6jHOVtvsya0_fBDS-xnPQ) for my code.

Below is the sample working code.

## 1. We are creating two Table with schema dynamically

```
$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient();
try{
            $res = $bigQuery->dataset(DATASET)->createTable($owner_table, [
           'schema' => [
            'fields' => $ownerFields
           ]
       ]);
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        //echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage(); 
        //die();
        $custom_error_message = "Error while creating owner table schema. Trying to create with ".$ownerFields;
        sendErrorEmail($e->getMessage(), $custom_error_message);
        return false;
    }
```

## 2. Import two CSV from GCS into created tables.

```
$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
]);
$dataset = $bigQuery->dataset($datasetId);
$table = $dataset->table($tableId);
// load the storage object
$storage = new StorageClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
]);
$object = $storage->bucket($bucketName)->object($objectName);
// create the import job
$job = $table->loadFromStorage($object, $options);
// poll the job until it is complete
$backoff = new ExponentialBackoff(10);
$backoff->execute(function () use ($job) {
    //print('Waiting for job to complete' . PHP_EOL);
    $job->reload();
    if (!$job->isComplete()) {
        //throw new Exception('Job has not yet completed', 500);
       // sendErrorEmail("Job has not yet completed", "Error while import from storage.");
    }
});
```

## 3. Run Big Query to find some matches from both table.

```
{
  //Code omitted for brevity
}
```

## 4. Big Query returns the result as array in php. Then We are creating the 3rd table and inserting the query result set into it.

```
$queryResults = $job->queryResults();
if ($queryResults->isComplete()) {
    $i = 0;
    $rows = $queryResults->rows();


    $dataRows = [];
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        //pr($row); die();
       // printf('--- Row %s ---' . PHP_EOL, ++$i);
        ++$i;
        $inlineRow = [];
        $inlineRow['insertId'] = $i;
        foreach ($row as $column => $value) {
           // printf('%s: %s' . PHP_EOL, $column, $value);
            $arr[$column] = $value;


        }
        $inlineRow['data']= $arr;
        $dataRows[] = $inlineRow;
    }



    /* Create a new result table to store the query result*/

        if(createResultTable($schema,$type))
        {

            if(count($dataRows) > 0)
            {
                sleep(120); //force sleep to mature the result table
                $ownerTable = $bigQuery->dataset(DATASET)->table($tableId);
                $insertResponse = $ownerTable->insertRows($dataRows);

                if (!$insertResponse->isSuccessful()) {
                    //print_r($insertResponse->failedRows());
                    sendErrorEmail($insertResponse->failedRows(),"Failed to create resulted table for".$type);
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            else 
            {

                return 2;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            return 0;
        }



    //printf('Found %s row(s)' . PHP_EOL, $i);
}
```

## 5. We are trying to export the 3rd table which contains the result set to GCS.

```
function export_table($projectId, $datasetId, $tableId, $bucketName, $objectName, $format = 'CSV')
{
    $bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
        'projectId' => $projectId,
    ]);
    $dataset = $bigQuery->dataset($datasetId);
    $table = $dataset->table($tableId);
    // load the storage object
    $storage = new StorageClient([
        'projectId' => $projectId,
    ]);
    $destinationObject = $storage->bucket($bucketName)->object($objectName);
    // create the import job
    $options = ['jobConfig' => ['destinationFormat' => $format]];
    $job = $table->export($destinationObject, $options);
    // poll the job until it is complete
    $backoff = new ExponentialBackoff(10);
    $backoff->execute(function () use ($job) {
        //print('Waiting for job to complete' . PHP_EOL);
        $job->reload();
        if (!$job->isComplete()) {
            //throw new Exception('Job has not yet completed', 500);
            return false;
        }
    });
    // check if the job has errors
    if (isset($job->info()['status']['errorResult'])) {
        $error = $job->info()['status']['errorResult']['message'];
        //printf('Error running job: %s' . PHP_EOL, $error);
        sendErrorEmail($job->info()['status'], "Error while exporting resulted table. File Name: ".$objectName);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The Problem is on #5. As the 3rd Table in #4 is in streaming buffer the export job is not working successfully.

Sometimes it is able to export the table correctly and sometimes it is not done.  We have tried to give a sleep between #4 and #5 about 120 seconds but the problem remains.

I have seen that the table generated dynamically via API is in streaming buffer for 90 mins. But this is too high.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! You should consider adding a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: You lost me at _"However as soon as I did it, Streaming buffer is created before actual table is populated with data. It is taking around 90 minutes to mature the table."_. You're on the right track - issue your query, write the results to a table and then export that table to GCS as csv. Not sure why you started talking about streaming. Can you share your code? Also, do you have to do this PHP? You could use a simple Dataflow pipeline to do the same in one shot.

Comment: I have added the sample code for better understanding. As I am naive to this platform as well as Google big query I could not find a work around. 
I have also googled for Data flow pipeline. I couldn't find an working example in PHP. 

It seems Dataflow pipeline is avaiable in JAVA and Python. Another thread on it as
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868015/write-bigquery-query-result-directly-to-gcs-is-it-possible

Comment: Hi P K Ghosh, when replying to someone's comment, make sure to add their name preceding with an "@" like "@GrahamPolley" so they receive a message in their inbox of your comment.

Comment: I wonder if you try to stream data in chucks of say 500 rows per insert for instance if it helps.

Comment: Thank you "@WillianFuks". I will keep it in mind.
My problem is never at inserting data in result big query table. It was while I tried to export that result table as CSV file in GCS. Moreover currently my result table size is not more than 100 rows.